# Remove symlinks originating from specific directory

Tags: shell, find, symlink, rm, ln

I have an "install.sh" that installs my personal scripts:

```
find /home/Steven -name '*.sh' -exec ln -s -t /usr/local/bin {} +
```

I would like to make an "uninstall.sh" that removes the symbolic links created
by "install.sh". I wrote this:

```
for z in /usr/local/bin/*
do
  if [ -h "$z" ]
  then rm "$z"
  fi
done
```

but it removes all symlinks, not just ones where the target is under
"/home/Steven".

Comment: @StevePenny It occurred to me that there are a couple of minor possible ambiguities in the question related to symbolic links. The first is whether or not you're using absolute or relative paths when creating the symbolic links. The second is whether or not the targets of the symbolic links are links themselves. I suspect that neither of these will be issues in your specific case (as described in the question body), but it might be something to keep in mind.

Comment: @igal you can see my command - so that answers at least one of the questions

Comment: @StevePenny That's right. If you're only ever using absolute paths then that's not going to be an issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have GNU or BSD `find`, this should do it:

```
find -lname '/home/Steven/*' -delete
```

Comment: @TavianBarnes This seems like a better solution. But this won't work if the symbolic links use relative paths, will it?

Comment: @igal Right.  That shouldn't be a problem in this specific case, because the links were created with absolute paths as seen in the question.  In general it would be hard to use `find` to answer the question "does this symbolic link point somewhere under this directory?"

Answer (score 1):

You could modify your script and use `grep` and either `readlink` or `realpath` to extract the files in the desired subdirectory, e.g.:

```
for z in /usr/local/bin/*
do
  if [ -h "${z}" ] && readlink -f "${z}" | grep -q '^/home/Steven'
      then rm "${z}"
  fi
done
```

The `readlink -f` command returns the full path to the file pointed to by the symbolic link. The `grep -q '^/home/Steven'` command returns true if the path begins with the substring '/home/Steven' and returns false otherwise.

A word of caution: there is some ambiguity related to symbolic links that could affect the outcome here. The `readlink -f` command will resolve the link recursively, so the above command would fail if the file in the `/home/Steven` directory were itself a symbolic link point outside of this directory. If this isn't the desired behavior then you might want to use the `realpath` command instead.

Answer (score 1):

To cover for the case where the links may be relative and to check that their canonical path is within `/home/Steven`, with `zsh`:

```
rm /usr/local/bin/*(@e{'[[ $REPLY:A = /home/Steven/* ]]'})
```

Where:

- `@` glob qualifier that matches on symlinks:
- `e{code}` glob qualifier that matches based on the evaluation of the code (where `$REPLY` contains the path of the file to check)
- `$REPLY:A` expands to the absolute path of `$REPLY`.